# MIPS: color bitmap based on a text file (mars-sim)

Tags: bitmap, mips, mars-simulator

So I basically get a text file with letters in a grid format with every letter representing a certain color for example:

```
bbbb  
brbr 
ybbb
```

b = blue, r = red and y = yellow

But I've been kinda stuck on how you could possibly convert into the MARS bitmap tool. When you use the build-in syscall instruction to open and read the file then the whole file just gets stored into a register. How would you make it so that you can read every letter individually so that you can store it in the right pixel of your bitmap?

Comment: _"the whole file just gets stored into a register"_ No, it get read into memory. So keep reading chunks of data from the file into memory, and then parse the data that you have read.

Comment: aah I see, I had a totally wrong understanding of how the instruction worked thanks for the tip!